# I got many warning and error when installing truffle

Tags: truffle

I run the code 'npm install -g truffle' also tried 'npm install truffle',
but the result is the same, here is the warning and error I got.
When I try to install truffle, this show to me. I don't know how to fix it.

Example:

```
npm WARN deprecated testrpc@0.0.1: testrpc has been renamed to ganache-cli, please use this package from now on.
npm WARN deprecated safe-event-emitter@1.0.1: Renamed to @metamask/safe-event-emitter
npm WARN deprecated mkdirp-promise@5.0.1: This package is broken and no longer maintained. 'mkdirp' itself supports promises now, please switch to that.
```

Comment: Doesn't look as if you can. https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/3986

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're working on transferring webpack init boilerplate over to Box structure which caused the depreciated errors, simply update your node to v16 or v17 LTS and run the following to install:

```
npx truffle unbox webpack
```